# What is that black thing in center of every star in this JWST image?

Tags: nasa, james-webb-telescope

I circled that black thing in this image with blue color:
[image]

The image above, which NASA released on Wednesday (July 6, 2022), represents 32 hours of observing time
from JWST's Fine Guidance Sensor.

Comment: "I circled that black thing in this image with blue color:" Great. Now how long until someone posts this image asking "What are these blue things in this JWST image?" :)

Comment: @Acccumulation If I feel that question is **useful** to this community, then I definitely upvote it.

Comment: Could you link the original image in the question?

Comment: @Acccumulation your username is oddly perfect to point that out.

Comment: @Acccumulation "I pointed those blue things out with red arrows..."

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The stars in the image are so much brighter than any of the other galaxies that their centers ended up grossly overexposed. Remember, stars are small and should show up with one single pixel only (to be precise, a few pixels if we take optical sharpness of the telescope into account) - everything else is just stray light.

At some point in the acquisition process these overexposed pixels got replaced with black ones. As @Vorbis points out, CMOS pixel sensors (1) have the tendency to not being able to handle vastly overexposed pixels well: Each detected photon produces an free electron in the sensor - if too many are present in one pixel, the electric potential generated by the semiconductor is not strong enough to hold them back. This causes nearby circuits to be affected and e.g. the reference voltage getting distorted so much that the generated output of the pixel effectively becomes zero and therefore indistinguishable from a black pixel.

It could as well be a deliberate decision to clearly mark them later in the processing chain. This could have happened already in the digitization stage, the on-board processing or in the earth-based post-processing that created the false colors shown in the image we are shown.

In the description of the image NASA didn't go into detail either:

> the centers of bright stars appear black because they saturate Webb’s detectors

https://blogs.nasa.gov/webb/2022/07/06/webbs-fine-guidance-sensor-provides-a-preview/

(1) JWST doesn't use a regular CMOS pixel sensor, but special sensors made from HgCdTe for infrared detection. The read-out circuitry still is built into a CMOS chip and therefore likely affected by the mentioned effect.
Some details about the sensor architecture can be found in
[The HxRG Family of High Performance Image Sensors for Astronomy by Blank et al.](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2011ASPC..437..383B/abstract). A sketch of the setup can be found on the third page. The difference between this sensor and a regular CMOS sensor is that detector material and electronics material are separate, but they remain closely connected with individual bump bonds for each pixel.

Also: This effect is distinct from the well known blooming experienced with CCD sensors.

Comment: This is a strange explanation. Isn't it more sensible to show max brightness for saturated pixels? After all, it's what the sensor gives out. Or was it intended to mark unusable points?

Comment: @Ruslan If they were marked as max brightness, you wouldn't be able to tell how close the real value was to the max brightness displayed. The overexposure could have been 10% higher than max brightness, or 10E5 times higher. A black pixel removes the risk of misinterpreting the over-exposed pixels as being close/at the threshold of the sensor.

Comment: @johnDanger what makes me wonder is why they don't similarly mark/process the diffraction glare. It also makes one misinterpret the data if it's taken uncritically.

Comment: @Ruslan, the sensor can directly report when a particular pixel has become saturated.  There is no way for the sensor to distinguish between diffracted light and direct light.

Comment: if the Webb telescope uses a CMOS sensor, it's probably the "black sun" effect: it's unwanted (and unavoidable) and it's directly tied to the CMOS technology. See here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6386896/

Comment: @Vorbis That might well be. Interestingly the circles are a bit sharper than I'd expect.

Comment: @Vorbis it's not a CMOS sensor, it's a HdCdTe array since it has to operate in the infra red (0.8 to 5.0 microns in this case). More details on the FGS [here](https://jwst-docs.stsci.edu/jwst-observatory-hardware/jwst-fine-guidance-sensor)

Comment: @astrosnapper: Good find.  HgCdTe (not Hd) are the elements it's made of, but that doesn't tell us *how* they're used.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_cadmium_telluride says: *In HgCdTe, detection occurs when an infrared photon of sufficient energy kicks an electron from the valence band to the conduction band. Such an electron is collected by a suitable external readout integrated circuits (ROIC) and transformed into an electric signal. The physical mating of the HgCdTe detector array to the ROIC is often referred to as a "focal plane array".*

Comment: So yes, using a [ROIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readout_integrated_circuit) means not CMOS, where the digital logic is built in to the sensor, from the same semiconductor material as the sensor.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active-pixel_sensor#Comparison_to_CCDs).  CdTe is a semiconductor, according to wikipedia, but IDK if it would even be plausible to use it for anything beyond photon detection.

Comment: Compared to a CCD (where the buckets (pixels) that hold charge carriers until they're read out are on a separate chip), wiki says *A CMOS sensor also typically has better control of blooming (that is, of bleeding of photo-charge from an over-exposed pixel into other nearby pixels).* Of course, the context there is room-temperature visible-light sensors, but I don't expect low-temperature HgCdTe to be immune to stray electrons leaking around.  This is the guidance camera, not intended for science data directly, so it might(?) have less effort into a super high dynamic range to avoid bleed.

Comment: Err wait, but the black sun effect is not just bleeding into adjacent pixels.  Black sun might well be specific to CMOS, where the analog to digital converter (ADC) and associated logic is on the same silicon as the image sensor itself, so it can be affected by stray electrons from a highly over-exposed pixel.  With a CCD, you could still get a bloom around a bright spot, but it would probably read out as *max* brightness, not black.

Comment: It doesn't matter if pixel and readout are in the same chip or not. The question is: Where is the integrating capacitor. I assume it's on the read-out side and therefore inside a regular CMOS chip.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes HgCdTe.(Not sure what happened there, some autocorrect shenanigans as I cut and pasted from the JWST NIRCam site...lol). The detectors are Rockwell (now Teledyne) HAWAII-2RG detectors, a [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228882031_High-performance_focal_plane_arrays_based_on_the_HAWAII-2RG4G_and_the_SIDECAR_ASIC) on them has somehow escaped the SPIE paywall

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I dug up re: the plausibility of [Vorbis's suggestion](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/59680/what-is-that-black-thing-in-center-of-every-star-in-this-jwst-image#comment197794_59682) of the "black sun" effect (where *the **reference voltage** in a CMOS sensor gets distorted so much that the generated output of the pixel effectively becomes zero and therefore indistinguishable from a black pixel.* as summarized by @asdfex).

The FGS uses a HgCdTe sensor which is probably CCD, not CMOS, but I haven't found a definitive statement to that effect.  Unfortunately I haven't been able to rule out or confirm the black sun effect being a thing for the FGS in the JWST, but I'm posting what I did find as a starting point for others, and/or as getting part way to an understanding of image sensors.

---

The black-sun effect can happen because CMOS sensors put the analog to digital converter (ADC) and associated logic on the same semiconductor as the photo-sensitive parts.  That makes it susceptible to stray electrons from a highly over-exposed pixel.

As opposed to a CCD, where there's a separate [ROIC (readout integrated circuit)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readout_integrated_circuit) to collect the charge in each bucket (pixel).  In that case you can still get bleeding of stray electrons into neighbouring pixels, over-exposing them, but I suspect the charge buffering and collection would still work correctly.  So stars would show up as *max* brightness, not black.

(In fact, generally [CMOS is worse than CCD for bleed effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active-pixel_sensor#Comparison_to_CCDs) at least for silicon at room temp for visible light, probably because it can collect and digitize more frequently for any given pixel, so over-exposure is less of a problem.  But unfortunately that part of Wikipedia doesn't mention immunity or lack thereof to the black-sun effect.)

---

**The question becomes whether the JWST's sensor is CMOS or CCD.**

The elements its made of are [HgCdTe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_cadmium_telluride), where CdTe is a semiconductor with a bandgap of 1.5V, and mixing in some mercury can lower the bandgap.  The JWST operates it at about 37 Kelvins.

Wikipedia says (in general about HgCdTe detectors that have to be cryo-cooled to at most 77 K):

> In HgCdTe, detection occurs when an infrared photon of sufficient energy kicks an electron from the valence band to the conduction band. Such an electron is collected by a suitable external readout integrated circuits (ROIC) and transformed into an electric signal. The physical mating of the HgCdTe detector array to the ROIC is often referred to as a "focal plane array".

**This implies that the *normal* construction is CCD, with a separate ROIC.**

I don't know if it would even be plausible to use it for anything beyond photon detection via charges; the material is a semiconductor, but building active logic in it would require doping it with something to create junctions.  The wiki article does mention undoped vs. doped, which is probably necessary to create separate cells to hold charge for each pixel.

Unanswered questions:

- Electrical construction details of the FGS sensor (CCD vs. CMOS), although my research indicates that CCD is more likely for HgCdTe sensors.
- Whether CCDs in general (or this one in particular, or HgCdTe CCDs) can be affected by a black-sun effect.
- Ultimately, whether the FGS could be affected by a black-sun effect.  If I had to bet on it, I'd put the odds at maybe 50% that it could be affected.  (I'd have gone lower if not for the existence of this image with black spots for suns, since that would neatly explain things.)

---

The pixels being black might have gotten that way straight from the sensor via some kind of black-sun effect that affects whatever sensor type the JWST's FGS uses.

Or it's possible that fully-saturated pixels get marked black to distinguish them from almost-saturated pixels.  This could conceivably happen pretty early in the sensor internals, although doing it in software would make more sense to avoid throwing away information in hardware.  IDK why that would make sense, though; software that was looking for stars for guidance purposes could just as easily search for max-brightness.

Or perhaps it's done in software for human benefit, as part of a standard rendering setup they use.

Comment: https://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/2011ASPC..437..383B   It's a hybrid CMOS sensor with the readout electronics right on the back of each pixel. Essentially it behaves like a regular CMOS sensor, just with the photosensitive layer slightly offset on a different die but directly connected with bump bonding.

Answer (score 3):

This happens a lot even in amateur photos. Most modern monitors still only display colors using 8 bits per color (8 for red, 8 for green, 8 for blue).  But the cameras now capture way more detail than that, a pretty common file format stores 12 bits per channel.  No doubt JWST camera go way beyond that.

So the pixels in the image have to be downscaled through a process called [tone mapping](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://skylum.com/blog/what-is-tone-mapping&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwi-5-3V5O74AhWslYkEHQowBxAQFnoECAsQAg&usg=AOvVaw1atK4SfiP13ml8-a8-GvrK). This usually requires human intervention to get an image that looks good, highlighting details in the places of interest while throwing other details away.

Since this was an engineering image, likely no manual tone mapping was done, and the black spots are just a result of the pixels with too high of a number being discarded and defaulting to 0 by the file format used for the web.

[Example image](https://www.cloudynights.com/topic/740211-dss-loses-center-of-stars/)

Comment: The whole image is a product of mapping tone, color and intensity. Otherwise it would be just grayscale and not black/white/red/yellow.

Comment: Your "Example image" was posted by an amateur, asking for help with how to configure the image processing software that they used. I'd like to think that whoever prepares images for NASA's public facing web sites could do better than that. Have a look at the "Black Sun Effect" mentioned by @vorbis in a comment, above. IMO, that would be a happier explanation.